# How to get .Net Core 3.1 Azure WebJob to read the AzureWebJobsStorage connection string from the Connected Services setup?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-webjobs, .net-core-3.1, azure-webjobssdk

I'm building a WebJob for Azure to run in an App Service using .Net Core 3.1.
The WebJob will be triggered via Timers (it's basically a cronjob).

Timer triggers require the `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection string as storage is required for Timer events.

When deployed to Azure App Service, I want the WebJob to read the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value from the properties on the App Service.

I have a Resource Manager template that deploys my infrastructure and sets the connection string on my App Service resource:

```
          "connectionStrings": [
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('_StoreAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('_StoreAccountName')), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]"
            }
          ],
```

When testing my WebJob locally, I need to set that `AzureWebJobsStorage` value so that my local builds can connect to storage.

Since I re-deploy the infrastructure all the time as I make tweaks and changes to it, I do not want to manually maintain the long connection string in my `appsettings.json` or a `local.settings.json` file.

In Visual Studio, In theory, I can add a Service Dependency to the project for Azure Storage and that will store the connection string in my local `Secrets.json` file. Then, when I redeploy the infrastructure I can use the Visual Studio UI to edit the connection and re-connect it to the newly deployed storage account (i.e. it will create and update the connection string without me having to do it manually).

When I add Azure Storage as a connected service, Visual Studio adds a line like this in my `Secrets.json` file:

```
  "ConnectionStrings:<LABEL>": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<LABEL>;AccountKey=_____________;BlobEndpoint=https://<LABEL>.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://<LABEL>.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://<LABEL>.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://<LABEL>.file.core.windows.net/",
```

and this in my `ServiceDependencies/serviceDependencies.local.json`:

```
    "storage1": {
      "resourceId": "/subscriptions/[parameters('subscriptionId')]/resourceGroups/[parameters('resourceGroupName')]/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<LABEL>",
      "type": "storage.azure",
      "connectionId": "<LABEL>",
      "secretStore": "LocalSecretsFile"
    }
```

and this in my `ServiceDependencies/serviceDependencies.json`:

```
    "storage1": {
      "type": "storage",
      "connectionId": "<LABEL>"
    }
```

Where `<LABEL>` is the name of the Storage Account (in both JSON snippits).

When I run the WebJob locally, it loads the `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Development.json`, `secrets.json`, and Environment Variables into the IConfiguration.

However, when I run the WebJob locally it dies with:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'Functions.Run' was unable to start.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.get_TimerStatusDirectory() in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 77
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusBlobReference(String timerName) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 144
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusAsync(String timerName) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 93
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Listeners.TimerListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Listener\TimerListener.cs:line 99
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.SingletonListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\SingletonListener.cs:line 72
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowRetry) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 69
```

I have confirmed that if I add the `ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage` value to my `appsettings.json` then the program runs fine.

So I know it's an issue with the loading of the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value.

**Has anyone figured out how to get an Azure WebJob, running locally, to properly read the connection string that Visual Studio configures when adding the Azure Storage as a Connected Service?**

What's the point of adding the Connected Service to the WebJob if it won't read the connection string?

(note: I realize that the WebJobs docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#webjobs-sdk-versions state that `Because version 3.x uses the default .NET Core configuration APIs, there is no API to change connection string names.` but it's unclear to me if that means the underlying WebJobs code also refuses to look in the Connected Services setup or if I'm just missing something)

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around, but I don't like it... basically check if there's a `ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage` value at the end of my `ConfigureAppConfiguration` code and if not, try and read the one from the `secrets.json` file and set the `ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage` to that value.

```cs
private const string baseAppSettingsFilename = "appsettings.json";
private const string defaultStorageAccountName = "<LABEL>";

...

IHostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder();
...
builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.AddJsonFile(
         path: baseAppSettingsFilename.Replace(".json", $".{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json"),
         optional: true,
         reloadOnChange: true);
    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development")
    {
        c.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
    }
    // Add Environment Variables even though they are already added because we want them to take priority over anything set in JSON files
    c.AddEnvironmentVariables();

    IConfiguration config = c.Build();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(config["ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage"]))
    {
        string storageConnectionString = config[$"ConnectionStrings:{defaultStorageAccountName}"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(storageConnectionString))
        {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException($"Could not find a ConnectionString for Azure Storage account in ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage or ConnectionStrings:{defaultStorageAccountName}");
        }
        c.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage", storageConnectionString }
        });
    }
});
```

This seems exceedingly dumb but even looking at the Azure SDK source code I'm thinking it's just hard coded to a single key name and the Service Configuration in Visual Studio is simply not supported: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/afb81d66749eb7bc93ef71c7304abfee8dbed875/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Scheduling/StorageScheduleMonitor.cs#L77

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO, however the example code given is too verbose the AddInMemoryCollection is the critical line which should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem where VS2019 automatically configured Function and Function1 with Connection = "ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage" and it couldn't find that.  Simply changing it to Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage" worked like a charm.

FYI - I also had to change BlobTrigger("Path/{name}"... to BlobTrigger("path/{name}"...
re: [Microsoft.Azure.StorageException: The specified resource name contains invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58265382/microsoft-azure-storageexception-the-specified-resource-name-contains-invalid-c)